# TFS: Checkin mistakenly made before a branch

Tags: version-control, tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

I was starting a a feature, made a few working changes and then we(management and architect) decided to create a new branch for this feature.

The issue is that I already made some checkin (and other users have some other non-conflicting changes after), and those checkins have to be "removed" of their current branch, then put on the new branch.

Do you see a way to do this without having to make a copy of all the files I modified(120 files, in very different parts of the application), rollback ma changes, then checkout all the modified files in the new branch, and copy files with my modification?

We are using TFS(2010 if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Side note: Your TFS 2010 server drops out of primary support next month!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1) Branches can be made retrospectively, so the easiest is to ditch the branch you created and simply create a new branch that is taken from the change-set (or date/time, or label) just prior to your unwanted check-in. If you have some later check-ins that you still want to keep in the branch, just merge them into the new branch as normal. (note: branches are very lightweight, as they essentially only hold the differences from the mainline, so the branch you are abandoning will not use up much disk space because it's near-unchanged)

2) Or check out the affected files in the branch, copy over them with the previous version, and then check them in again to "roll back" the unwanted change-set. (This is a much more laborious and error prone approach though - I'd go for option (1) unless there was a good reason not to)

Comment: The new branch is not yet created ;) But, I cannot do what you indicate: the new branch must contains my new changes, and must be put to the new branch

Comment: j4n, you will need to redo your changes in the new branch... Learn from the experience.

Comment: j4n, just branch it from the last changeset before the unwanted changes, and then merge any subsequent changesets that you need across. If you're going to create a branch, you will almost certainly have to merge at some point, so you can't really start branching without also learning how merging works.